# How to Modify the StrongLoop's LoopBack Explorer CSS

Tags: css, user-interface, loopbackjs, strongloop

We're using Strongloop's LoopBack for our REST APIs and would like to modify the CSS for the LoopBack Explorer. However, it's not clear which CSS files are being used (LoopBack vs Swagger) and where they're located. I was not able to find specific documentation for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can provide your own version of Swagger UI files via `options.uiDirs`.

1. Edit your `server/server.js` and add this config option to the explorer:

   ```
   app.use(explorer(app, { uiDirs: path.resolve(__dirname, 'explorer') }));
   ```
2. Copy the directory `node_modules/loopback-explorer/public/css` to `server/explorer/css`
3. Customize the copied CSS files as you need.

You should lock loopback-explorer's major & minor version in your package.json. Newer versions of loopback-explorer may change the CSS in which case your customization may stop working.

Comment: Miroslav's answer is correct. I deleted mine since it's incorrect.

Comment: I did this in server js  file and  add  dir server/explorer/all public files
app.use(explorer(app, { uiDirs: path.resolve(__dirname, 'explorer') }));
Ui is changed but there is no API.?

Comment: @PPB i am also getting same issue, how you resolved this issue

Comment: I get following error after adapting this change TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function

Comment: @Think-Twice see https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-component-explorer/blob/master/README.md#upgrading-from-v1x. You need to use `explorer.routes()` instead of `explorer()` now.

Comment: @MiroslavBajtoš Thanks for your reply. I have applied custom css styles as mentioned in my newly added answer under this question

Answer (score 13):

You can modify more than just the css. And also, if you generate your Loopback application using `slc loopback` like I did, you'll find that your `server/server.js` doesn't look immediately in a way you can configure it like it's shown in the accepted answer.

Instead you can use `server/component-config.json` to instruct the loopback component explorer to use an alternative directory for static files for the swagger-ui. With the `uiDirs` configuration below I configured it to go look for static files in the `server/explorer` directory.

```
{
  "loopback-component-explorer": {
    "mountPath": "/explorer",
    "uiDirs": "server/explorer",
    "apiInfo": {
      "title": "My API",
      "description": "Description of my API"
    }
  }
}
```

** When using IISNode `uiDirs` has to be set to `"explorer"` otherwise it's `"server/explorer"` as per @phegde 's comment*

In my server directory I created a index.html which is a copy from `node_modules/loopback-component-explorer/public/index.html` and also I created an images folder with a custom logo.

[image]

And finally, If you want to have custom css, copy `node_modules/loopback-component-explorer/public/css/loopbackStyles.css` into `server/explorer/css/loopbackStyles.css`

Comment: With me it does. If you want help, do an analyses and ask a question on SO.

Comment: if explorer folder is inside the server, the `uiDirs` must be `"server/explorer"`. This was the fix.

Comment: @phegde I updated my answer to reflect that. `uiDirs` had to be `"explorer"` when using iisnode. Otherwise, it's what you said.

Comment: Color has changed but I am unable to override the logo name

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't lock the loopback-explorer in package.json or if you started your application from the new release of loopback(v2.x),  you have to make another change:

1. If you generated your loopback app with the generator tool, edit `server/component-config.json` and change it to this:

   {
     "loopback-component-explorer": null
   }

2.Copy the directory `node_modules/loopback-explorer/public/` to `server/explorer/` as Miroslav said. If you copy the whole directory you can also change the index.html file.

3. Edit `server/server.js` file and add this line: `app.use('/explorer',explorer.routes(app, { uiDirs: path.resolve(__dirname, 'explorer') }));` also you have to add the explorer module at the top of the file: `var explorer = require('loopback-component-explorer');`

4.Customize the ui of your explorer, all the necessary files are in `server/explorer`

Answer (score 0):

With the `loopback-component-explorer` the `uiDirs` defined in `component-config.json` should be added something like the below (which solved my issue).

```
"uiDirs": ["server/explorer"]
```

instead of

```
"uiDirs": "server/api-explorer",
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to apply custom css styles to loopback api explorer header.

Steps I followed as mentioned below

> 1. Goto node_modules > loopback-component-explorer > public > css folder
> 2. Copy loopbackStyles.css
> 3. Create a new folder called explorer under server folder
> 4. create css folder under explorer and paste the css file under css folder i.e., loopbackStyles.css
> 5. Add below config to component-config.json file

```
{
  "loopback-component-explorer": {
    "mountPath": "/explorer",
    "generateOperationScopedModels": true,
    "uiDirs": "server/explorer"
  }
}
```

To change loopback header color I have just overrided `backgroun-color` with my own color in `body #header` css selector in `loopbackStyles.css`

To replace the default header logo name with our custom name. I have added following css styles in `loopbackStyles.css`

```
.swagger-ui-wrap #logo{
  display: none;
}
.swagger-ui-wrap:after { 
  content: "MyOwn API Explorer";
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold; 
}
```