# How can I change Loopback API explorer header color and name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I am using `loopback` framework in my `node.js` service. I have loopback API documentation generated.

My query is how can I change `loopback API explorer` header background color and header name. I went through many blogs to figure out the solution for this use case but none of them provides details.

Kindly suggest if anyone made this possible. Appreciate your time. Thanks in advance.

Please bear with me as I don't no which code should I post in question for solution.

Comment: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073421/how-to-modify-the-strongloops-loopback-explorer-css) might solve your concern.

Comment: Thank you. I saw the answer looks like loopback explorer css files will exist in node_modules and as well as wr we copy them. Correct?